# Kendo datasource read undefined after adding record in ds

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, ko.observablearray

I got stuck in a problem with kendo datasource.
I created the datasource array , because i have multiple grid to bind . The way i access the datasource is

```
ds[1] . ds[0],
```

When i execute `ds[1].read();` it works fine and get the data from server.

As soon as i add a record into `ds[1].add( json data)` and try to read the datasource it give error `undefined`;

```
     dsSupplier[ActivetabRank].read();
$.each(tempArray.OrderDetailModel, function (key, value) {
dsSupplier[ActivetabRank].add({
"ParkOrderId": 0,
"itemDesc": value.ItemDesc,
"itemQty": 0,
"Supplier": {
"SupplierID": tempArray.SupplierModel.SupplierID,
tempArray.SupplierModel.EFax, "IsActive": true,
},
});
});

});
```

Comment: Please add definition of the datasource, its very hard to find you what is wrong from the code you've included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't include definition of your datasource, so I will try to guess: Make sure you defined id in your model. I would suggest to follow quite strait forward example from the [kendo doc](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-add). The fact datasources are in an array does not effect any functionality.

```
 schema: {
    model: { id: "ProductID" }
  }
```